# What's the difference between "transfer" and "transference"?

Tags: word-choice

Does their use depend on the context? Or are both words utterly equivalents?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

They are not the same. Transfer means generally to move something from one place to another. The thing can be anything that can be moved from place to place.

Comment: Elliot, you're a bit less than half right. Your first paragraph is accurate (though unsubstantiated), but your second paragraph is wrong on multiple counts. Firstly, *[transference](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/transference)* ordinarily means "The action of transferring something or the process of being transferred." There is indeed a more specific meaning in psychoanalysis, but your description also has several errors. This is why we strongly recommend that answers include supporting evidence. For further guidance, see [answer] and take the EL&U [Tour]. :-)